# Change content of `div` as per bootstrap dropdown items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap nav bar. In which i have multiple drop-down items.

Now I have another `div` `col-md-3`.

In this div I want show the items of the dropdown which I hover. For now if i hover over a dropdown then the submenu is showed instead of clicking.

So how can I show the sub items of a drodown menu in that div ?

I want that subitems are in drop-down and also in that side bar div.

My Code is like this:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a  href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Time Zone</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Holidays</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Working Hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"> Promt Language</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Phone No Allocation & Extensions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Speed Dial</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Confernce Welcome Message</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dial Plan<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Current Dial Plan</a></li>

                  <li><a href="#">Caller ID Management</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ISD Management</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Block Number</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Override</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
               </ul>

            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Routing<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">24 Hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Working Hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">OFF Hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"> Location Based Routing </a></li>
               </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Call Recording</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Users <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Add User</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">View Users</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Voice Mail<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Default</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">For each user</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Provisioning <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Manual Softphone Configuration</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Add Deskphone</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>

               </ul>
            </li>

         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12" >
            <!-- Side bar-->
                <div class="col-md-3">

                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Comment: @Leothelion I am not using but i believe i will have to use jquery so i have put a tag for jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, however it seems you forgot to include jQuery in your code.
I created a Codepen using your code and I've included jQuery.js at the bottom just before including the Bootstrap library.
As you can see the dropdown items work fine and, as you remove the jQuery script from the code, you can reproduce your broken scenario.

Here is the link: [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/andreasonny83/pen/MegBPw)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @andy but how will the dropdown content be showed in the other div as well ?

Comment: dropdown is not the issue i want that the dropdown menu items are also show in another div